# Dataframe substitution of For loop

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I have a dataframe with Latitude, Longitude, summedDistance and runingDistance columns.

I used the code bellow and it works:

```
summedDistance = 0
for i in range(0, len(dfLatLong)-1):
    fromLocation = (dfLatLong.loc[i, "Latitude"], dfLatLong.loc[i, "Longitude"])
    toLocation = (dfLatLong.loc[i+1, "Latitude"], dfLatLong.loc[i+1, "Longitude"])
    summedDistance += Helper.fromtoDistance(fromLocation, toLocation)
    dfLatLong.loc[i, 'runingDistance'] = Helper.fromtoDistance(fromLocation, toLocation)
    dfLatLong.loc[i, 'summedDistance'] = summedDistance
```

(the Helper function uses the geodesic distance between sequential rows of latitudes and longitudes)

Is there a way to use map or apply so I can eliminate the For loop?

Thanks

Comment: try numpy.select()

Answer (score 0):

Use from_lat , from_long instead of merging I to a single column. You need to pick up the latitude column from 1:n-1 and add a null at the end and assign it to the to_lat column in one go.

You can then use the apply function once all data is well aligned.

Comment: Thanks Tarik. That's one way to go. I'll try it and post the code here.